# Printing multiple list in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, format

Hello I am trying to create the table below by using list. The product s and the prices are already in lists (priceList and productList). i have successfully created new more list where the person types in the product code  and quantity (quan_inputed).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't know what to do. I have tried several methods already and this is the closest I've come to getting multiple inputs at once.

Thank you

Comment: please add a minimal reproducible example rather than screenshots, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: this condition does not make any sense: `if code_1 not in code_inputed > 1`

Comment: You are doing code_inputed.append(code_inputed), which effectively means that code_inputed[-1] = code_inputed so you get the index error when iterating over code_inputed with kk, you try to use kk as a list index with priceList[kk] and quan[kk].

Comment: You are using value from first list as a index to the second list, this is not right. You can either use enumerate in your for loop:
`for idx, kk in enumerate(code_inputed):` and then use idx as index into the other list.
Or IMHO better approach - use List of Dictionaries or some other data structure to store all info of one product into one line. Then iterate through this list and you'll get all the info you need for your table print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]    Try This:

```
def add_item():
    code_inputed = []
    quan_inputed = []
    while True:
        i = input("enter code: ")
        if i != "END":
            q = input("enter quantity: ")
            code_inputed.append(int(i))
            quan_inputed.append(int(q))
        else:
            break
    return code_inputed,quan_inputed

def showRecord(code_inputed, quan_inputed):
    product_info = {}
    for kk in range(len(code_inputed)):
        quan = quan_inputed[kk]
        kk = code_inputed[kk]
        price = priceList[kk]
        product = productList[kk]
        if kk not in product_info:
            product_info[kk] = [kk, quan, price, product]
        else:
            product_info[kk][1] += quan
            product_info[kk][2] = product_info[kk][1] * price
    for x in ["Code", "Quanity", "Price", "Product"]:
        print(x, end="  ")
    print()
    for x in product_info:
        for info in product_info[x]:
            print(info, end="     ")
        print()

code_inputed, quan_inputed = add_item()
showRecord(code_inputed, quan_inputed)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply it works just as good as I hoped. Is there any way I can sort the code from smallest to largest though. I tried using code_inputed.sort() but it changes the index making the code and quantities inputed not match up. Is there another way I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain my comment about the other approach, I recommend storing the data in other way than just in multiple lists. For example like this:

```
items = [
    {'code': 2, 'price': 39.95, 'quantity': 11, 'product': "Tea Set\t\t"},
    {'code': 34, 'price': 19.95, 'quantity': 3, 'product': "Citrus Cather"}
]

print("Code\tProduct\t\t\tPrice $\tQuantinty\tCost $")
print("------------------------------------------------------")
for item in items:
    print(f"{item.get('code')}\t\t{item.get('product')}\t{item.get('price')}\t{item.get('quantity')}\t\t\t{item.get('price') * item.get('quantity')}")
```

Those tabs (\t) in product name in dictionary are just to make the table nice, you should come up with nicer way to print it...

Result:

[image]